# How to upload an extra image on new discussion and use as featured image of discussion?

Tags: vanilla-forums

For a project I'm developing with Vanilla forum, I want to have option to allow user to add featured image in Vanilla forum post. I want this featured image to be displayed on homepage along with all the posts that are displayed by default (without any featured image).

As I'm relatively new to Vanilla forum development, I'm unable to figure out:

1. How do I provide user the option to upload featured image with each post at the time of posting new? I've tried using file upload plugin, but this inserts image in "gdn_media" database table having no connection with discussion ID.
2. How to customize select query of Vanilla forum to retrieve additional field, if I had to get featured image say from media table or a custom-made table of mine?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please have a look at the [guides for asking questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking), specifically [how to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.